# Убрать "web" из адреса в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, apache

На хостинге установлен `yii2-basic`, установлен не в корень, а в `htdocs/basic`.

Хочу `http://домен/basic/web/about` заменить на `http://домен/basic/about`.

На данный момент последний адрес перенаправляет на главную страницу.

В `basic` лежит следующий `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ web/index.php
</IfModule>
```

В `basic/web` тоже лежит `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

В `config/web.php`:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        '' => 'site/index',
        '<action>'=>'site/<action>',
    ],
],
```

В `'request'` добавление `'baseUrl' => ''` даёт 404.

Comment: Не забанили. Способ выше не сработал

Comment: Попробуйте вот так в rules `'basic/about' => 'basic/web/about'`

Comment: Вы, наверное, имели ввиду `'basic/web/about' => 'basic/about'`, но не работает(

Comment: 'baseUrl' => 'basic'

Comment: @ilyaplot, т.е. вопросам на которые есть ответ на тостере здесь не место?

Comment: @UrmuzTagizade работает, но крашится front-end

Comment: Как вы подключаете скрипты? Через layout или через registerScript и registerCss? Если не через layout, то прописывайте в начале пути /

Comment: Я только начал изучать фреймворк... С этим еще не работал

Comment: Оформил как ответ. все должно сработать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сам не раз сталкивался с клиентами, у которых был обычный хостинг, где не было возможности прописать корневую директорию.

Вот как я решал данную проблему:

**1)** В корне проекта создаем **.htaccess** с содержимым:

[image: Наглядный пример]

> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>     Options +FollowSymlinks
>     RewriteEngine On
> </IfModule>
>
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.*
>     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ basic/web/$1 [L]
>
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/basic/web/
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>     RewriteRule ^.*$ basic/web/index.php
> </IfModule>
> ```

**2)** В папке **web** создаем **.htaccess** с содержимым:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

**3)** Далее открываем файл **config/web.php** и делаем следующее:

Находим строчку

```
'request' => [
    'cookieValidationKey' => .......,
],
```

И добавляем в массив строчку `'baseUrl' => ''`

```
'request' => [
    'cookieValidationKey' => .......,
    'baseUrl' => '',
],
```

**4)** Заранее забегаю вперед и пишу, как убрать ещё и **index.php**

Находим строчку в файле **config/web.php**

```
'urlManager' => [
     ........ //остальная часть кода
],
```

И добавляем в массив строчку `'showScriptName' => false`

```
'urlManager' => [
     'showScriptName' => false,
     ........ //остальная часть кода
],
```

Данная инструкция уместна для структуры папок, указанной Вами. Обычно проект заливают в корень сайта. В таком случае убираем в первом пункте basic и наслаждаемся жизнью :)

Comment: не работает - крашит верстку. буду искать решения дальше...

Comment: Внимательно все посмотрели и сделали? 1 пункт особенно