# Yii2 проблема при удалении /web из url на локальном хосте при помощи .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, yii2

Всем привет. Проблема заключается в следующем:
при помощи .htaccess хочу сделать чтобы в url вместо *хост/web/site/index* отображалось *хост/site/index*. В инете есть тема как это сделать, вот тут https://toster.ru/q/210872. Однако, когда я создаю .htaccess вставляю туда:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(web)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ web/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /web/index.php
```

Затем в корневой папке добавляю строку **'baseUrl'=> '',** в **request** в **config/web.php** то при попытке зайти на сайт браузер выдает следующее:
*Not Found
The requested URL /web/index.php was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25 Server at localhost Port 80*

В качестве сервера использую пакет WAMP. И по моему месяца 2 назад я проделывал эту же операцию и все работало. Я пробовал переустанавливать WAMP, но результат все тот же. Я пошел дальше и закинул этот же проэкт на бесплатный хостинг в инете, и что забавно там все прекрасно работает с этими .htaccess, а на локалке такая беда. В общем я потратил не один день на поиски решения этой проблемы, сдался и пришел сюда просить помощи.
Никак не могу понять где собака зарыта. Я нуб. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: А разве web не должна быть корнем сайта?

Comment: Так и есть. По идее можно настроить apache чтобы web была корнем, но в моем случае хотелось бы сделать это именно через .htaccess файлы. Я не могу понять почему браузер выдает эту ошибку 404 на локальном сервере, ведь раньше все работало+я залил все на хостинг в инете и там это работает как положено. Не могу понять в чем дело :С

Comment: @Megumin боюсь спросить зачем тебе это? если фреймворк специально сделан для вызова из веб папки как единая точка входа, зачем это менять?

Comment: А случаем раньше у тебя не стояла другая версия `php` или `apache` (или и то и другое) ?   может дело именно в них..........также в папке web, должен быть еще один `.htaccess`....... а также попробуй инструкции [Установка yii2 + base template на локальный компьютер Linux/ubuntu](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/512995/191482) и [Что написать в .htaccess и конфиг yii2 basic для дефолтной маршрутизации?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/517861/191482)

Comment: Как я упомянул выше я новичок и по этому могу лишь предположить что проблема скорее всего в настройках апач, т.к. на вебхостинге темплейт открывается с этими настройками, а на локалке выдает 404 ошибку. Я не знаю как убрать эту 404 ошибку и в чем причина её появления, за этим я тут чтобы разобраться в этом :С

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/626443/180583

Comment: Проблема у автора решилась (судя по его удаленному ответу), но есть аналогичный вопрос с ответом: [Убрать "web" из адреса в Yii2](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/626185/%d0%a3%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-web-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b2-yii2)