# Переход на другую страницу в yii

Tags: php, yii2

Есть главная страница, которая рендерится в контроллере `my`. При переходе на другие страницы всё нормально.
Но при попытке перейти обратно на главную в адресной строке вместо `www.dipl1/web/my`  генерируется `www.dipl1/web/my/my` и, соответственно, ошибка.
Ссылка на главную и все остальные страницы:

```
<li><a href="my">Главная</a></li>
                <li><a href="db">Работа с БД</a></li>
                <li><a href="diagram">Графики с данными</a></li>
```

Все представления находятся в папке `my`

Comment: Добрый вечер. Скажите, как Вы генерируете ссылки для yii2? Так как Вы показали или используете helpers?

Comment: Как показал. До helpers пока не доходил

Comment: Используйте helpers для формирования ссылок, избежите проблем в будущем.

Comment: А чем именно он помогает?

Comment: Попробуйте свои ссылки сделать при помощи yii\helpers\Html, в документации почитайте. Увидите разницу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не правильно указали ссылки:

```
<li><a href="/web/my">Главная</a></li>
<li><a href="/web/my/db">Работа с БД</a></li>
<li><a href="/web/my/diagram">Графики с данными</a></li>
```

Comment: Так не работает. Внёс небольшую правку в вопрос

Comment: @Андрей внес правки в ответ, попробуйте так.

Comment: Нет, не работает

Comment: @Андрей странно, а вообще у вас страницы открываются по ссылкам: http://www.dipl1/db или ttp://www.dipl1/my/db  ?

Comment: http://dipl1/web/my/db. Методы для рендеринга страниц находится в контроллере my

Comment: Спасибо. Работает. А так вообще можно? Не нарушает каких-то правил и тд?

Comment: @Андрей Нет, почему что-то должно нарушаться? А как убрать /web из url это уже другая история...  Вот например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/626185/Убрать-web-из-адреса-в-yii2